# how to get jdbc null object from table

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have an sql column PROTOCOL  of Number type .It is nullable  and a constraint on the table
PROTOCOL IN(1,2,3).I am able to set to null. How to get the value if its null?
I can do rs.getInt() but I dont think it returns null?

```
if(protocol==0)
            {

               stmt.setNull(15, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);                

           }
            else{
            stmt.setInt(15, protocol);
            }
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920364/checking-for-a-null-int-value-from-a-java-resultset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `wasNull()` method.

```
 Integer myValue = rs.getInt(15);
 if (rs.wasNull()) {
   myValue = null;
 }
```

Comment: If the value is null what will  the  myValue be here doesn't it throw exception? Integer myValue = rs.getInt(15);

Comment: (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(java.lang.String)) says that it will be 0.

Comment: I can also try...... Integer myValue = rs.getInt(15);
 if (rs==0) {
   myValue = null;
 }

Comment: (I suppose you meant `if(myValue==0)`) - You can then not distinguish between `0` and `null`, but according to your constraint that might do it. I would still prefer an explicit handling of the `NULL` value, though.

Answer (score 3):

> I can do rs.getInt() but I dont think it returns null?

Use [ResultSet.wasNull()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) after `getInt()` to check if the last column read was NULL.

Or, use [ResultSet.getObject()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) instead of `getInt()`, which returns `null` if the column is `NULL`.