# Null database column becoming zero on resultSet

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I cant show you my database structure... but i can try to do an example:

```
Table Car_Manufacturer 
(
  car_id NUMBER;
  manuFacturer_id NUMBER;
)
```

Values:

```
|TABLE CAR_MANUFACTURER   |
| CAR_ID |MANUFACTURER_ID |
|    1   |     1284       |
|    2   |    (null)      |
```

Select that my resultSet receives:

```
select * from CAR_MANUFACTURER where car_id = 2
```

I can get the CAR_ID:

```
int id = rs.get("car_id");
```

the output from id value:

```
2
```

But, when i try to get MANUFACTURER_ID the null value becomes an integer:

```
Integer manId = rs.get("manufacturer_id");
```

Output manId

```
0
```

Any idea? I need to get NULL value... not an integer value.

Comment: Alternative duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920364/checking-for-a-null-int-value-from-a-java-resultset?rq=1

Comment: but... this solution doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Check the accepted answer here: [How do I in JDBC read a possibly null double value from resultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103460/how-do-i-in-jdbc-read-a-possibly-null-double-value-from-resultset).

It gives you a way of knowing whether the value read was null and defaulted to some value when rs.getXXX was called.

Comment: If you come across a duplicate then you should flag (or close vote) as duplicate, not post an answer that is essentially pointing to the duplicate question.

Comment: doesnt work for me... because, when the MANUFACTURER_ID contains any value, the rs.wasNull returns TRUE.

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro The correct order of asking is `rs.getInt("MANUFACTURER_ID"); rs.wasNull();` (so immediately after getting the column value). If that doesn't work then it is a bug in the JDBC driver.

Comment: i'm doing exactly this way... but i'm using rs.getLong

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro That should work as well. Make sure you are using the latest version of the Oracle JDBC driver. And otherwise you may have to resort to using `getObject` instead.

Comment: i think... probably my jdbc driver is out of date. Because, i tried to getObject to Long variable, and doesnt work too.